# Is it possible to run Xcode11 in macOS Big Sur?

Tags: xcode, macos-big-sur

I get following error:

```
The version of Xcode installed on this Mac is not compatible with macOS Big Sur. Download the latest version for free from the App Store.
```

This is on a M1 Mac (ARM, Apple Silicon).

Comment: Is this issue related to M1 chip or the latest macOS BigSur? Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the message it looks like it's due to BigSur but I haven't tried it on a non-M1 @JTN

Comment: Has anyone tested running Xcode 11 on Intel Macs yet?

Comment: @MJQZ1347 On Intel Macs, Xcode 11.7 opens in macOS 11.7.5 without any trickery

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I was able to bypass the macOS denial-prompt, to run Xcode 11.7 on Big Sur (11.0.1) on my M1 MacBook Air, by running the executable directly from Terminal– for example:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
```

I just needed to compile, archive, and export a specific app, and it at least worked for that.

Comment: It open and compiles, thanks! However, if I try to run in simulator, the debugger cannot be attached, I always get "Could not attach to pid / Failure Reason: LLDB provided no error string"

Comment: Hello Michael, Do you have any previous experience about developer termination?

Comment: I wonder if the method described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/70300916 works in this instance.