# How can I run older Xcode version on new macOS version?

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-monterey, macos-ventura

I am facing a problem running older versions of Xcode on newer MacOS versions.
For example, Xcode 13 on MacOS Ventura.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The solution is very simple. If you have the older version downloaded in your Applications folder for example, lets say `12.5.1` version, you just need to:

- Open Terminal
- Open Applications folder in Finder
- Drag the Xcode app into Terminal so it gets its path
- Then add this next to it: `/Contents/MacOS/Xcode`, so the full command will be something like `/Applications/Xcode-12.5.1.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode`
- Press enter to run the command

Now you should be able to run it. You will note that when you open this version of Xcode, the Terminal will open too, but don't close Terminal because it will close the Xcode too.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=xcode) you can find older Xcode versions.

Comment: Why can't you just run the app?

Comment: @Willeke: because macOS Monterey requires Xcode 13 and above

Comment: I added this as a shell script shortcut. Worked great! Makes you wonder just why Apple refuses to let it run under Monterey...

Comment: Xcode 12.0.1 works too, using the  same way.

Comment: If I go terminal/Shell/New Window/Basic then it doesn't work - get an "It says no such file or directory" error. I had to do Terminal/Shell/New Window/Homebrew to get it to work

Comment: Right click on XCode app and show package content than go to ContentsMacOS/Xcode double click to open

Comment: @MichaelLong On Intel Mac the Xcode 12 works perfectly fine on Monterey. However on Apple Silicon Mac, there have some compatibility issues such as unable to attach to a Mac Catalyst app process.

Comment: This workaround also works on macOS Sonoma & Xcode 14.3.1.

Comment: You can download and unzip older Xcode releases from here:

https://xcodereleases.com/

you may have to run `sudo` in front of the open command but once you do that you'll get the xcode version you want and can run it successfully

Comment: This is not working for older versions, like 9.4 for example I get this :

dyld[78285]: Symbol not found: (_OBJC_IVAR_$_NSFont._fFlags)
  Referenced from: '/Applications/Xcode 9.4.1.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit'
  Expected in: '/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit'
[1]    78285 abort      /Applications/Xcode\ 9.4.1.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode

Comment: I have the same problem as @mehdigriche trying to start Xcode10.3 on Sonoma. I need to compile something for an old iPod Touch running iOS 12.5.7 and I can't :'(

Comment: Maybe on Sonoma this command is not working for the very old Xcode versions. I'm really curious why anyone would use Xcode 9/10 now?

Comment: found the issue, it's because XCode 9 is built on 32-bit and apple stopped supporting it in newer MacOS version.

Answer (score 67):

Change the paths to OLD/NEW Xcodes and run script. The script will change the build version of the old Xcode to the new one, run it and restore. Script needs to be run once, after that Xcode can be opened via double click

Works on macOS Monterey for Xcode 12.5.1, Ventura for Xcode 13, Sonoma for Xcode 14

```bash
#!/bin/sh

set -euo pipefail

# Set the paths to your Old/New Xcodes
OLD_XCODE="/Applications/Xcode_14.3.1.app" # or /Applications/Xcode_13.4.1.app on Ventura
NEW_XCODE="/Applications/Xcode.app" # To get build number

# Get New Xcode build number
OLD_XCODE_BUILD=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" ${OLD_XCODE}/Contents/Info.plist)
NEW_XCODE_BUILD=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" ${NEW_XCODE}/Contents/Info.plist)

echo The Old Xcode build version is $OLD_XCODE_BUILD
echo The New Xcode build version is $NEW_XCODE_BUILD

# Change Old Xcode build version to New Xcode
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion ${NEW_XCODE_BUILD}" ${OLD_XCODE}/Contents/Info.plist

# Open Old Xcode (system will check build version and cache it)
open $OLD_XCODE || true

# Revert Old's Xcode's build version
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion ${OLD_XCODE_BUILD}" ${OLD_XCODE}/Contents/Info.plist
```

Comment: I think this answer should be marked as Accepted.
Really good approach for "daily" usage.

Comment: as @Mert AYDIN wrote, to find out what is CFBundleVersion of your current Xcode version, use this command to be able to run the accepted answer as your Xcode version might be something else instead of 13.1  `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" /Applications/Xcode_12.4.app/Contents/Info.plist`

Comment: Concur, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: in the first answer by @stakich, I wouldn't open projects.

Comment: this solution is not working for **Xcode_10.X** which they say i need to migrate my **Swift 3** projects to **Swift 4**.

Comment: Still working on Ventura if anyone interested

Comment: ChatGPT taught me how to follow this answer like a true newbie, lol.
Btw it worked for me on MacOS Sonoma and Xcode 14.3.1
https://chat.openai.com/share/4dd50735-ec9a-4e95-9e2d-ffa547b396e4

Comment: Works in Sonoma. Xcode_14.3.1

Answer (score 6):

This is how you get your xcode's current build version.

```sh
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" /Applications/Xcode_12.4.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: To find out what is CFBundleVersion of your current Xcode version, use this command to be able to run the accepted answer as your Xcode version might be something else instead of 13.1

@Mert AYDIN thanks, adamsın :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a solution without using terminal every time, here it is:

1. Follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/69995053/14199447
2. Create a bash file with this content

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   /Applications/Xcode-12.5.1.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
   ```
3. Open terminal, run `chmod 700 YourBashFile.sh`
4. Change the default opening app of YourBashFile to terminal.
5. Follow step 1 and 2 of this https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/407885 to create an executable application which you can put on your Dock. After this you should be able to use the new app like any other app.

Answer (score -2):

1. Download and install older Xcode releases from here:

https://xcodereleases.com/

2. Login will be required with your Apple Developer credentials.
3. Download and uncompress installer:

e.g. Xcode_13.4.1.xip

4. from Terminal run:

   open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
5. Accept agreement and setup any development parameters as needed.