# Could not run XCode 9.1 on MacOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, migration

I am trying to migrate my Swift 3 code to Swift 4 to meet the requirement of Apple. I downloaded Xcode 9.1, renamed it to `Xcode9.1.app`, and moved it to the Applications.

I tried to open it as explained in the following link: [How can I run Xcode 12.5.1 on Monterey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69994916/how-can-i-run-xcode-12-5-1-on-monterey). But it quits.

The quitting message is:

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               Xcode [14762]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode9.0.1.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               9.0.1 (13249)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-13249000000000000~2 (9A1004)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2022-01-10 11:36:20.3726 -0600
OS Version:            macOS 12.0.1 (21A559)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     6.0 (19P549)
Anonymous UUID:        A485806D-0882-7796-CC9C-BB31F6F3E237

Sleep/Wake UUID:       22979CA9-B8DA-4613-99F5-34DE333FABB8

Time Awake Since Boot: 570000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       7415 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace DYLD, Code 1 Library missing
Library not loaded: @rpath/XCTest.framework/Versions/A/XCTest
Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode9.0.1.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
Reason: tried: '/Applications/Xcode9.0.1.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/../../../../Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/Versions/A/XCTest' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode9.0.1.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/../../../XCTest.framework/Versions/A/XCTest' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode9.0.1.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/../../../../Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/Versions/A/XCTest' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode9.0.1.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/../../../../Frameworks/XCTest.framework/Versions/A/XCTest' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode9.0.1.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/XCTest.framework/Versions/A/XCTest' (no such file), '/Applicat
(terminated at launch; ignore backtrace)

Application Specific Information:
Library not loaded: @rpath/XCTest.framework/Versions/A/XCTest
Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode9.0.1.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
Reason: tried: '/Applications/Xcode9.0.1.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/../../../../Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/Versions/A/XCTest' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode9.0.1.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/../../../XCTest.framework/Versions/A/XCTest' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode9.0.1.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/../../../../Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/Versions/A/XCTest' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode9.0.1.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/../../../../Frameworks/XCTest.framework/Versions/A/XCTest' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode9.0.1.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/XCTest.framework/Versions/A/XCTest' (no such file), '/Applicat


Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                                   0x10c9c60ce __abort_with_payload + 10
1   dyld                                   0x10c9dc1cf abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 80
2   dyld                                   0x10c9dc201 abort_with_payload + 9
3   dyld                                   0x10c98a613 dyld4::halt(char const*) + 375
4   dyld                                   0x10c98655d dyld4::prepare(dyld4::APIs&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer const*) + 3955
5   dyld                                   0x10c9854b4 start + 388


Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000002000209  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x00007ff7baf28a28  rdx: 0x00007ff7baf28e90
  rdi: 0x0000000000000006  rsi: 0x0000000000000001  rbp: 0x00007ff7baf28a70  rsp: 0x00007ff7baf28a28
   r8: 0x00007ff7baf28a90   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000000000096  r11: 0x0000000000000246
  r12: 0x0000000000000096  r13: 0x00007ff7baf28e90  r14: 0x0000000000000001  r15: 0x0000000000000006
  rip: 0x000000010c9c60ce  rfl: 0x0000000000000246  cr2: 0x0000000104fe7000
  
Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000209 
Trap Number:     133


Binary Images:
       0x10c980000 -        0x10c9ebfff dyld (*) <1a6ae033-9438-33c0-8077-988fd885250a> /usr/lib/dyld

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 41
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 935

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=991.7M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=991.7M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=9636K written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=9636K(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
STACK GUARD                       56.0M        1 
Stack                             8192K        1 
VM_ALLOCATE                         16K        3 
__CTF                               759        1 
__DATA                            31.2M      376 
__DATA_CONST                      12.0M      180 
__DATA_DIRTY                       534K      106 
__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 
__LINKEDIT                       661.8M       47 
__OBJC_RO                         81.5M        1 
__OBJC_RW                         3120K        1 
__TEXT                           329.9M      386 
__UNICODE                          588K        1 
dyld private memory               1024K        1 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              1.2G     1106
```

Comment: https://xcodereleases.com/ check the chart!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem

According to apple, macOS 12 requires you to use Xcode 13.

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=ufox?.ci5

## Solution

There is a way to install only the tool chain for Xcode 9, but not the
app itself. I'm not sure if Migration is possible through the command
line but it seems like the best solution.

https://github.com/mrpippy/XcodeNueve