# How to install XCode 6.4 in Mac Mini M1 MacOS 12.5 Monterrey

Tags: xcode, build, apple-m1

im facing an error while im trying to install a very old version of Xcode in this case 6.4 (downloaded directly from here [Apple Official Site](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=xcode%206.4)) a this point im already done all of this steps [How can I run Xcode 12.5.1 on Monterey?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70300916/14925835), but when im trying to run the application in the second step by running this command:

```bash
open /Applications/Xcode_6.4.app
```

the app just stop before it starts and throw this error message:
[Error window with details img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUlA4.jpg)

If this information are valid im trying to compile this specific project in my mac m1 https://github.com/360Controller/360Controller

Comment: 6.4 was made long before M1 switch, I doubt Rosetta is even designed to handle that. Even if you succeed, the fact that the program can't even be compiled on Xcode 7 likely means even if you somehow succeed to compile it, the result won't run on your M1.

Answer (score 1):

Your start up error running [Xcode 6.4](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW364) on Monterey:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (STGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
Exceotion Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:  Namespace DYLD, Code 1 Library missing
Librarv not loaded: '/usr/lib/libauto_dylib'
Reason: tried: '/usr/lib/libauto_dylib' (no such file), '' (no such file)
```

Xcode 6.4 released with support for High Sierra forward. Big Sur had some major changes, one of which is removing /usr/lib/libauto_dylib.

**In short, there is no way to run Xcode 6.4 on Apple Silicon**

Also, should you be able to compile the linked TattieBogle Xbox 360 Driver, it has a notice:

> As of December 28, 2020, there are not plans to add Big Sur support, including Apple Silicon support. It will most likely not work on Big Sur.

The reason it will most likely not work are many, but much of the kernel driver/extension features changed in Big Sur forward. **So even if you did get it compiled, it still would not load on Monterey**.