# Unable to use Xcode 13.0 on macOS Ventura

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I want to run Xcode 13.0 on the latest macOS but cannot open the Xcode file in the latest macOS.
is there any way to run the old Xcode on the latest macOS 13.0?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I run Xcode 12.5.1 on Monterey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69994916/how-can-i-run-xcode-12-5-1-on-monterey)

Comment: Please see this thread [How to use Xcode 13 in Mac OS Ventura](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74192400/how-to-use-xcode-13-in-mac-os-ventura) it might solve your problem :)