You can’t use this version of the application “Xcode.app” with this version of macOS
You can’t use this version of the application “Xcode.app” with this version of macOS.
You have “Xcode.app” 15.4.
I just updated to macOS sequoia and I am seeing this error and there's no update available for Xcode, maybe it's too early?

There is Xcode 16 available on this link: https://developer.apple.com/download/applications/, but if you try to download you get 403 Forbidden. You can download Xcode 16.1 beta though. Maybe we should wait a day or two.

Xcode 16 is a free download on the Mac App Store. (I think that's why it is not available at the URL given in the earlier comment.) https://apps.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12

I just got an update of Xcode 16 from App Store, thanks!

try this solution to run xcode 15.4 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69994916/how-can-i-run-older-xcode-version-on-new-macos-version

I just got an update of Xcode 16 from App Store
